# error when sending a notification 'Call to undefined method App\Models\Role::routeNotificationFor()'

Tags: notifications, laravel-8

I am building a web app whereby after an admin(with the role of a manager) approves a booking, the booking passes to another admin(with the role of an accountant) who then starts working on it.I want the manager to send a notification to only the accountant after approving the booking.i tried this code below and it sends to all admins which is not what I want to achieve

```
    $users=User::where('is_admin','1')->get();
    Notification::send($users,new Newbookingrecieved($bookingstatus));
```

then i tried getting the email from the role model
$users=Role::where('Role_name','The Accountant')->get();
Notification::send($users,new Newbookingrecieved($bookingstatus));

but it responded with an error

BadMethodCallException
Call to undefined method App\Models\Role::routeNotificationFor()

here is my notification

```
<?php

namespace App\Notifications;

use App\Models\Bookings;
use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notification;

class Newbookingrecieved extends Notification
{
    use Queueable;

    public $bookingstatus;

    /**
     * Create a new notification instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($bookingstatus)
    {
        $this->bookingstatus = $bookingstatus;
    }

    /**
     * Get the notification's delivery channels.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return array
     */
    public function via($notifiable)
    {
        return ['mail'];
    }

    /**
     * Get the mail representation of the notification.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return \Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage
     */
    public function toMail($notifiable)
    {
        return (new MailMessage)
            ->greeting('Hello there sir/madam')
            ->subject('New Booking by' .$this->bookingstatus->full_name)
            ->line('We have received a new Booking and approved it to you to request payment from the client' . $this->bookingstatus->email)
            ->action('Review This Booking', route('changestatus', $this->bookingstatus->id));
                    
    }

    /**
     * Get the array representation of the notification.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($notifiable)
    {
        return [
            //
        ];
    }
}
```

here are all the roles [image]

how can i achieve this such that i send the notification to the only adminand the notification wont be sent to other admins.

Comment: Who exactly do you want the notification sent to? what role are you targeting?

Comment: @atika The accountant only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I don't know the structure of your `User` model, I will assume that there is a `role_id` field.

Here is a piece of my code from one of my old projects that I will modify to your liking (it works for me) :

```
$users = User::where('role_id', 3)->get(); //3 is the id of The Accountant role
Notification::send($users, new Newbookingrecieved($bookingstatus));
```